# Issue with direct URLS of Angular1.3 routing - even when html5mode is false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

If I'm navigating through the links, I'm able to open the respective views but if I copy paste the entire url, view is not loading & no errors in console.

Here is my config of main app module,

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
                .when('/welcome', {
                    templateUrl: 'src/app/welcome/welcome.html'
                })
                .when('/terminology', {
                    controller: 'TermsController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    templateUrl: 'src/app/terminology/term-table.html'
                })
                .when('/', {
                    redirectTo: '/welcome'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/welcome'
                });

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }]);;
```

Eg: 
1. If I click on home link, welcome view is loading in ng-view and the URL becomes (URL1) "http://localhost:8081/web/#/welcome"

2. If I click on terms link, terminology view is loading in ng-view & the URL becomes (URL2) "http://localhost:8081/web/#/terminology"

but If I copy paste the entire URL in a new tab, the view becomes blank. There is no error in the console. I'm using Angular1.3

ADDED:
Moreover, for the first time also default view is not loading...
Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you getting 404 error ?

Comment: No.. Nothing... just blank page. No template is loaded in ng-view

Comment: Even for the first time, default view is not loading.. :( No idea where I'm going wrong

Comment: Check the article at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-nested-views-routing-and-deep-linking-with-angularjs.htm

Comment: @Nikivancici, I have implemented this so many times. but in Angular1.3 I'm facing this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. 
My actual index.html file is like this

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>  
    <!-- my css files -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- this shell page contains "ng-view" directive which is causing the whole problem -->
    <div ng-include="'src/app/igl-layout/shell.html'"></div>

    <!-- my js files -->
</body>
```

now I replaced the content of shell.html to the above ng-include directive(line), then everything works fine.

**Can anyone tell me why this is happening?**
If ng-view is inside shell page, its not working as expected but if it is in index.html page its working fine.